# bootstraping angular4 app AppModule after a API call possible?

Tags: angular, bootstrapping

I want to call a API before angular4 AppModule is started/initialized. is this possible?

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        APP_COMPONENTS,
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(){
    console.log('Init. Module...');
  }
}
```

Before the bootstrap component 'AppComponent' initialized, i want to call a API.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: `APP_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: @Suren Srapyan I need to get few details from other system and based on that I app should be initialised.

Comment: Look at @yurzui recommended token